# How to check if list contains all the same values?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark

I have a `List[<DataType>]` as input. I want to check if the list contains all the same values(not datatype).

Is there inbuilt method or intuitive way in Scala to do this instead of iterating over list and checking.

Comment: "instead of iterating over list " Any solution must iterate over the list (at least until it finds a different element)

Comment: ok, good point. I was thinking more about if Scala has some more optimised construct then user iterating over list.

Comment: All the same data *type*, meaning `DataType` is a trait/abstract class?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, they are class. Present in org.apache.spark.sql.types

Comment: Do you want to match on the type itself, or the data inside the type?

Comment: type itself. I have @jwvh 's answer to the point about this.

Comment: Now you've confused things further. You've said you have  @jwh's answer , but that is about values, In your comment, and in the body of your question, you say you want to match types. But in your subject, you say values. Can you give an example of what you want to check and the expected output?

Comment: yes sure. 
list = List(StringType,DateType,BooleanType)
return fun(list)

output : false

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will terminate on the first non-equals element. The element type has to support a comparator like `==` or `!=`.

```
lst.forall(_ == lst.head)  // true  if empty or all the same
lst.exists(_ != lst.head)  // false if empty or all the same
```

Comment: `return (lst.toSet.size >1)`
How does this compare to your 2nd code complexity wise?

Comment: It's concise but I don't think it is more efficient. It might be a _little_ better on collections that are uniform (all values equal) but it is certainly worse if the collection is not uniform because A) it won't terminate early, and B) every element going into the `Set` has to be compared with every element already in the `Set`.  If the first 2 elements are not equal then every following element will be compared with **both** elements already in the `Set`. (BTW, the `return` statement is seldom seen in idiomatic Scala.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. Yes i know about return, i put it there so people can understand in what context i am asking.

Comment: Note that `lst` might be an empty list, and call `lst.head` would throw an exception. A version of this approach which is total for all lists (including empty lists) and returns `true` if the list is empty would be: `lst.headOption.fold(true){ h => lst.tail.forall(_ == h) }`

Answer (score 6):

One (inefficient but elegant) way is

```
List(1, 2, 2, 1, 1).distinct.length == 1 // returns false
List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1).distinct.length == 1 // returns true
List().distinct.length == 1 // empty list returns false
```

Note that they must be of the same type

```
List(4, 4.0, "4").distinct.length == 1 // returns false
```

Comment: this can be really inefficient

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do this for an unrelated problem, so to improve on the above ever so slightly: `lst.tail.forall(_ == lst.head)`. This avoids checking that the head of the list equals itself, which you already know is true.

Comment: This will throw if you try it on an empty Seq whereas the answer by @jwvh will return true.

Comment: What about `lst.drop(1).forall(_ == lst.head)`?

Comment: Taking of tail may be  (and in most cases would) less efficient than one additional comparison.