# Checking if a given element in all the tuples contained in the collection is equal

Tags: scala, collections, tuples, equality

Having a collection of tuples I would like to check if a given element in all the tuples is equal.

For example considering the second element of all tuples in this array should return `false`:

```
val a = Array((4,2), (8,1), (9,4), (10,2), (13,1))
```

While considering the second element of all the tuples in this array should return `true`:

```
val b = Array((4,3), (8,3), (9,3), (10,3), (13,3))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do it like this:

```
val a = Array((4,2), (8,1), (9,4), (10,2), (13,1))
val b = Array((4,3), (8,3), (9,3), (10,3), (13,3))

a.map(_._2).toSet.size == 1 // false
b.map(_._2).toSet.size == 1 // true
```

You can play with it [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/wYXWzXr/0)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
a.forall { case (key, value) => value == a.head._2 } // res2: Boolean = false
b.forall { case (key, value) => value == b.head._2 } // res3: Boolean = true
```

Note in the case of empty array `Array.empty[(Int, Int)]` this solution returns `true`.

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/41478838/5205022